# What's the libgeos-3.4.2.so? and how to install this?

Tags: django, ubuntu, geos

I'm using geodjango with postgresql, postgis.

I wrote some codes through django. But when i command
`python3 manage.py makemigrations` on my terminal (ubuntu 16.04 64bit)

terminal said `OSError: libgeos-3.4.2.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I think i already installed geos 3.4.2 from : https://trac.osgeo.org/geos/

and i tried install geos 3.4.2 more than twice after that terminal message.

but that error has not been vanished yet.

What should i do?

I already tried to install using way that geodjango documentations recommend. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#geos)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Why did you not install it with `apt`?

Comment: I'm very fool. I don't know what's package name to using sudo apt-get install ' ~~'. What is it?

Comment: i used `sudo apt-get install libgeos` But my terminal can't find package. sorry please let me know full command ? Is `sudo apt-get install libgeos` something gone wrong?

Comment: Oh never mind: they were dumb and put their version in the package title. Do `sudo apt-cache search libgeos` to find the relevant package title for your needs.